# gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance() is null and gapi.client.init never returns an error

Tags: javascript, google-api

I'm trying to make google API work in my code. 
I used quick start example, and made it work with my API key and the client id. But when I move the exact same function and it's parameters to my code:

```
initClient: function () {
    gapi.client.init({
      apiKey: this.API_KEY,
      clientId: this.CLIENT_ID,
      discoveryDocs: this.DISCOVERY_DOCS,
      scope: this.SCOPES
    }).then(function () {
      // Listen for sign-in state changes.
      gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.listen(this.updateSigninStatus);

      // Handle the initial sign-in state.
      //this.updateSigninStatus(gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get());
      //this.authorizeButton.onclick = this.handleAuthClick;
      //this.signoutButton.onclick = this.handleSignoutClick;
    }, function(error) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(error, null, 2));
    });
},
```

I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isSignedIn' of null`

Furthermore, the function(error) never procs, whatever I do with gapi.client.init parameters - delete them or put incorrect key - it never shows the alert. 
I use Chrome devs tools to make sure I don't run the old cached code or something.
What can be wrong?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue? If so, how?